# Windows Phone using Grid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a grid with 7 rows and 7 columns. I want to put in each cell a control dynamically.

To add the controls I use this code

```
Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle();

newRectangle.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(Rectangle_KeyDown);
newRectangle.Fill = HighlightColor;

Grid.SetColumn(newRectangle, i);
Grid.SetRow(newRectangle, ii);

grid1.Children.Add(newRectangle);
```

How can I get one of those controls from position `x,y`?

I thought something like

```
Grid.GetColumn( ?? );
Grid.GetRow( ?? );
```

But I don't know how to continue.

I realy hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in function for that so you should do the searching manually. But you can easily write such search function e.g with Linq:

```
var rectangleAtXy = grid.Children.OfType<Rectangle>()
    .SingleOrDefault(c => Grid.GetColumn(c) == x && Grid.GetRow(c) == y);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function for this. You have to read the attached properties `Row` amd `Column` of the grid's children to determine in which cell they are in.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish there but I might suggest a different, cleaner approach that might work for you.

It involves using a ListBox with a UniformGrid as the ItemsPanelTemplate. 
You would then create a Collection and set it as the ItemsSource for this List. You can now populate your list with your Controls using a simple transformation from a bi dimensional perspective (col, row) to a single dimension list (your list). Setting and retrieving the controls is now as simple as that transformation.